# How to deploy laravel app on digitalocean after succesfull test pass on Gitalab CI

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have managed to succesfully run laravel test build on Gitlab CI using Gitlab Runner on digitaocean (With help from tutorial [HOW TO: LARAVEL TESTING ON GITLAB CI WITH DOCKER](https://woohuiren.me/blog/how-to-laravel-testing-on-gitlab-ci-with-docker))

Now I am wondering how I can deploy it after succesfull test.

This is my deploy process on my staging env:

```
cd MY_PROJECT_ROOT_DIR
git reset --hard HEAD
git checkout master
git pull
composer install
composer update
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

How I can manage to include this deploy after test is done?

My configuration of GitLab Runner is the same as those files on this [repo](https://github.com/GIANTCRAB/gitlabby-dockerish-laravel)

This is the content of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - bash .gitlab-ci.sh

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

phpunit:php-laravel-env:mysql:
  image: woohuiren/php-laravel-env:latest
  services:
    - mysql:latest
  script:
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors
```

How I should change this file in order to execute deploy script after test passed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "stages"

Basically you would update your current test setup to include a stage.

```
stages: 
  - test
  - deploy

phpunit:php-laravel-env:mysql:
  stage: test
  image: woohuiren/php-laravel-env:latest
  services: ...

deploy_my_site:
  stage: deploy
  ...
```

These stages will get run in sequence by GitLab but will stop if there is any error.

If you are using Forge you could use the deploy stage to trigger a script to curl the forge deploy hook.